# Swift Instagram's profile view with its exact behaviour

Tags: swift, instagram

I have a problem where I have to create a view as similar as instagram's profile view. I have managed to get very close by digging into many solutions and I think I have found the best one for the purpose. I just need to get the final touch to resemble Instagram's profile view completely and I can't find the solution.

I leave the complete source code here so you can keep up with me: https://github.com/eduasinco/ProfileView

When you look at the project you will see a `headerView` on top of all other views, I have set the view of this header to be a `PassthroughView` which means that every action on that view will be ignored and pass to the next in the responder chain which in this case is one of the scroll views behind.

So far so good, nevertheless there is a small nuance, inside the header view there is a `segmentControlView` which is in charge of switching the pages, if you touch that segment control it will change pages just fine, the problem comes when you try to scroll the view from the `segmentControlView` it wont work. I would like to make this scroll behaviour happen as similar as Instagram's profile view.

To sum up, I would like to have a way to make `segmentControlView` work as it is doing now but also be able to scroll from it in the same way you can scroll when you are touching any other place inside the header view.
I have also tried all kinds of touch overriding but none of them works.

Any help will be appreciated