# Will a UICollectionViewCell be reused if the collection view is within a UIScrollView?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I appreciate that the answer to the title of this post may be "depends", but let me add some further info.

I am creating an app which contains a view similar to the profile page of Instagram. I have been struggling to come up with a way to best do this. My first attempts mainly used numerous collection views (including compositional layouts or flow layouts), however, although I got close, I was unable to come up with a solid solution using these methods.

My best attempt so far has been based on [Swift Instagram's profile view with its exact behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61653867/swift-instagrams-profile-view-with-its-exact-behaviour) and https://github.com/eduasinco/ProfileView, which I now have working to a satisfactory level. I recreated this programmatically and substituted out the table views for collection views, therefore there are some minor differences here and there.

My questions are:
Assume I have a collection view flow layout within a scroll view. The collection view height is set dynamically to the height of the content (i.e. number of items) and the collection view scrolling disabled. The height of the collection view is greater than the height of the scroll view, resulting in the vertical scroll behaviour coming from the outer scroll view;

Will all collection view cells be dequeued upon initial load - I have put break points in cellForItemAt for the collection view and upon scrolling the outer scroll view they are obviously not being hit?

Is this a problem performance-wise?

Is there a more preferred or "best practice" approach to take?

Comment: From my experience and if i properly understood the issue, never put UICollectionView inside UIScrollView, because you will struggle with height calculating, instead just consider that the UICollectionView inherits from UIScrollView, so no need to use UIScrollView as a parent view.

Comment: Thanks Osama Remlawi, this was my thought also and why I am hesitant with my current approach. The reason I have the scroll view is to allow for the collapsable header view to remain when paging horizontally. As the height of the content below the header will vary between horizontal pages, I don't think I can use a horizontally scrolling compositional layout, and adding a reusable header to a horizontally paging flow layout (which consists of another flow layout) will result in the header becoming one of the horizontal views... if that makes sense...

Comment: @Ben - it's difficult to get answers to questions that require us to "go look at some other app" or "go download and run this code." Short answer, though: If you set the frame of a collection view so ***all the cells are showing***, then yes, all cells will be rendered (dequeued) whether they are visible on-screen or not. As far as "performance" ... as you said, it "depends." Are you going to have 10 cells? Are you going to have **100** cells? ***500*** cells?

Comment: @DonMag, thanks for your comment. While I agree that questions requiring readers to "go and look at some other app" are not appropriate for SO, the paragraphs below and including "My questions are", stand alone from the background info above :) There is no need for readers to run code or go look at the instagram app based on the detail provided in the later paragraphs. You have however, confirmed my initial fears in that all cells will be rendered. This could be a potential issue for my app as it could have 100's of cells containing thumbnail images.